# Exchange Attribute msExchRecipientTypeDetails

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, adsi

I'm trying to get the value of `msExchRecipientTypeDetails` for a user using PowerShell and ADSI but I'm getting `System.__ComObject`.

I'm not able to move forward on getting the exact string.
I'm using below PowerShell command

```
$ADUsr = [ADSI]"LDAP://CN=User Name,OU=OrgUnit,DC=dc,DC=dc,DC=dc"
$ADUsr.msExchRecipientTypeDetails
```

And result are show below

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $ADUsr.msExchRecipientTypeDetails
System.__ComObject
```

How Can I get the exact string value? I'm expecting to get "2147483648" for UserMailbox

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to see the value of this property if i use a directory searcher to retrieve the user object:

```
$Searcher = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$Searcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=testuser))"
$Searcher.SearchRoot = 'LDAP://DC=test,DC=domain,DC=au'
$Object = $Searcher.FindOne()
$Object .Properties.msexchrecipienttypedetails
```

Or you can simply use the powershell cmdlet:

```
Get-aduser testuser -Properties msExchRecipientTypeDetails
```

Comment: Glad i could help, make sure you mark the question as answered for other people.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I can't use PS for AD. 
Tailored this to work how I wanted. I already have the user DN queried at the top of the script for another purpose

```
$UserDN = dsquery user forestroot -samid "USERNAME"
```

The rest to check for other attributes

```
$Searcher = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$LDAPPath = "LDAP://"+$UserDN
$Searcher.SearchRoot = $LDAPPath
$Object = $Searcher.FindOne()
$DisUsr = $Object.Properties.useraccountcontrol | Select -First 1 
$SGMembership = $Object.Properties.memberof 
$RecipientTypeDetails = $Object.Properties.msexchrecipienttypedetails | Select -First 1 
$RemoteRecipientType = $Object.Properties.msexchremoterecipienttype | Select -First 1
```